# Compute polygons (Data Driven Pages) main angle when having ArcGIS Basic license

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, polygon, data-driven-pages, angles

Is there a way we can calculate or when rotating polygons, actualize/update our "Angle" field in the attribute table by using Python? There is a tool in ArcGIS "calculate Polygon Main Angle" but is not supported by ArcGIS Basic license.

My code that works only in Standard license is:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

polygons = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
angle_field = "Angle"
rotation_method = "GEOGRAPHIC"

arcpy.CalculatePolygonMainAngle_cartography(polygons, angle_field, 
rotation_method)
```

Any hint ?

Comment: I have regular rectangels

Comment: Minimum Bounding tool does it, see options.

Comment: the think is that i get an orientation angle but it cant be used anymore by data driven pages as rotation angle you can use it but it doesnt fit in my map frame i hope you know what i mean but thank you anyways

Comment: No sorry, I don't understand, why can't it be used by DDP?  Once you have the angle from the minimum bounding, what if you forget DDP and just loop through your index features and set the dataframe properties using python (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm)?